# How, with JavaScript, does one map a list of names with aggregated data values from a related data-item list?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, filter, mapreduce

Maybe someone can give me idea how can i do it. So I have array of names `["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"]` and also I have array of objects which are purchase reports:

```
[
  { date: "19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 },
  { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 },
  { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 },
  { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom",  amount: 15 }
]
```

I need to get objects which represent a person and the amount they spend overall. `[{ name: "Tom", amount: 15 }, { name: "Mike", amount: 25 }, ...` I hope you get the idea. How can I achieve this? I try to `map` the names and filter array of objects but get `undefined`.

Comment: are Jane and John not included in the output?

Comment: hopefully, you won't have multiple users with the same name. Why are you not doing this in a database query?

Comment: Please go read [ask]. _“i try to map names and filter array of objects but get undefined.”_ - you are supposed to _show us_ what you tried, so please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: names in array are unique . Because it is exercise from internet just want to solve the problem :D. but don't have idea how to do it...maybe someone can give idea from where to start.

Answer (score 3):

Use a combination of map, filter and reduce to boil down the data:

The first .map is building the object structure, you want e.g. `{name: '...', amount: <val>}`

in order to get the value for each of the names, you filter the spending by name and reduce the outputed values by adding them.

```js
const names = ["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"];

const spendings = [{
  date: "19/02/2019",
  name: "Mike",
  amount: 10
}, {
  date: "20/02/2019",
  name: "Mike",
  amount: 15
}, {
  date: "21/10/2019",
  name: "Jane",
  amount: 25
}, {
  date: "22/03/2019",
  name: "John",
  amount: 30
}, {
  date: "19/03/2019",
  name: "Tom",
  amount: 15
}];



const result = names.map(name => {
  return {
    name,
    amount: spendings.filter(spending => spending.name === name).reduce((sum, {
      amount
    }) => sum + amount, 0)
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```js
const data = [
  { date: "19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 },
  { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 },
  { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 },
  { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom", amount: 15 },
];

const names = ["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"];

const results = names.map((name) => ({
  name,
  amount: data
    .filter(({ name: dataName }) => dataName === name)
    .reduce((total, { amount }) => total + amount, 0),
}));

console.log(results);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **Array.reduce** on your report array.

And reduce report array into dictionary of overall report for each name.

---

try first to solve it by your own.
this is my solution :

```
const dictionaryReports = reports.reduce((prev,curr)=>{
if(!prev[curr.name]) {
 return {...prev,prev[curr.name] : curr}
}else{
  return {
       ...prev,
        prev[curr.name]:
           { 
            ...prev[curr.name],
            amount : prev[curr.name].amount + curr.amount  
           }
         }
 } 
 
},{})
```

the output will be :

```
   dictionaryReports =  {
     Mike : {name:"Mike",amount:25},
     Tom : {name:"Tom",amount:15}
    }
```

then you can do

```
Object.values(dictionaryReports)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set it up however you like using the javascript filter method.

Eg. If you want to get entries in the array that match name and amount you can write a function like this:

```
const result = (name, cost) => array.filter(customer => {
    return name == customer.name && cost == customer.cost;
});
```

Running result("Jane", 25) will return this:

```
[{date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create an object with the wanted names and add the amount to each property.

```js
const 
    names = ["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"],
    purchases = [{ date:"19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 }, { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 }, { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 }, { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 }, { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom", amount: 15 }],
    result = purchases.reduce(
        (object, { name, amount }) => (object[name] += amount, object),
        Object.fromEntries(names.map(name => [name, 0]))
    );

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach is as generic as can be. It combines a [*`map`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and a [*`reduce`*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method in a way that **any data** from a given dataset (list of data) and a corresponding (target) value list **can be collected** for the latter from the former by just providing a start configuration to the above mentioned ***map-reduce*** combination ...

```js
const dataset = [
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Jerry",  amount: 45 },
  { date: "19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 },
  { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 },
  { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 },
  { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom",  amount: 15 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Jerry",  amount: 15 }
];


function aggregateTargetItemValueFromSourceKey(collector, item) {
  const { aggregateValue, sourceKey, targetKey, targetItem } = collector;
  if (targetItem[targetKey] === item[targetKey]) {
    targetItem[sourceKey] = aggregateValue(targetItem[sourceKey], item[sourceKey]);
  }
  return collector;
}

function createTargetItemFromBoundDatasetConfig(targetValue) {
  const { dataset, aggregateValue, initialValue, sourceKey, targetKey } = this;
  return dataset.reduce(aggregateTargetItemValueFromSourceKey, {
    aggregateValue,
    sourceKey,
    targetKey,
    targetItem: {
      [targetKey]: targetValue,
      [sourceKey]: initialValue
    }
  }).targetItem;
}


console.log(
  ["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"]
    .map(createTargetItemFromBoundDatasetConfig, {
      aggregateValue: ((targetValue, sourceValue) => targetValue + sourceValue),
      initialValue: 0,
      sourceKey: 'amount',
      targetKey: 'name',
      dataset
    })
);

console.log(
  [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
    .map(createTargetItemFromBoundDatasetConfig, {
      aggregateValue: ((targetValue, sourceValue) => targetValue.concat(sourceValue)),
      initialValue: [],
      sourceKey: 'name',
      targetKey: 'amount',
      dataset
    })
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

The second approach is a straightforward one, thus it is less flexible in the result it does produce. Nevertheless, there is at least the option of plainly aggregating the data from any item in the provided dataset, or, as the OP unintentionally might have hinted by the provided name list, one can use the latter for filtering only those items from the dataset list that are actually feature one of its names. ...

```js
const dataset = [
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Jerry",  amount: 45 },
  { date: "19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 },
  { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 },
  { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 },
  { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom",  amount: 15 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Jerry",  amount: 15 }
];
const itemNameList = ["Tom", "Jane", "Mike", "John"];

function aggregateItemAmountByItemNameWithOptionalNameCeck(collector, item) {
  const { checklist, index, list } = collector;
  const itemName = item.name;

  const isProceed = (!Array.isArray(checklist) || checklist.includes(itemName))
  if (isProceed) {
  
    let targetItem = index[itemName];
    if (!targetItem) {

      targetItem = index[itemName] = {
        name: itemName,
        amount: 0
      };
      list.push(targetItem);
    }
    targetItem.amount = targetItem.amount + item.amount;
  }
  return collector;
}


console.log(
  'with name check ... ',
  dataset.reduce(aggregateItemAmountByItemNameWithOptionalNameCeck, {
    checklist: itemNameList,
    index: {},
    list: []
  }).list
);
console.log(
  'without name check ... ',
  dataset.reduce(aggregateItemAmountByItemNameWithOptionalNameCeck, {
    index: {},
    list: []
  }).list
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the array reduce method on purchases. You don't need the array of names I think it looks useless for the result.

```
const purchases = [
  { date: "19/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 10 },
  { date: "20/02/2019", name: "Mike", amount: 15 },
  { date: "21/10/2019", name: "Jane", amount: 25 },
  { date: "22/03/2019", name: "John", amount: 30 },
  { date: "19/03/2019", name: "Tom",  amount: 15 }
]

const overall = purchases.reduce((acc, curr) => { 
     const currentUser = acc.find(x => x.name === curr.name);
     if(currentUser) {
        currentUser.amount += curr.amount;
     } else {
       acc.push({name:curr.name,amount: curr.amount})
     }
     return acc;
}, []);
```

[image: Output]